# Happiness of Purim

Tags: hebrew, purim

In Israel, many people wish each other Purim Sameach - have a happy Purim. Yet it seems those from chu"l wish Simchas Purim which translates as 'happiness of Purim. It would seem that purim sameach is a more accurate greeting.
Where does the term 'Simchas Purim' come from?  which term makes more sense?
*I know that this term is used in Halacha about breaking other people's property, I don;t think that is where it comes from*

Comment: Where have you heard this? How widespread do you know this to be? I for one have never heard that greeting.

Comment: I live in the US, and I don't recall hearing someone use *simchas Purim* as a greeting. I have heard *Purim Sameach* and *Chag Sameach* from those inclined to use Hebrew, *a freilechin Purim* for Yiddish, and "happy Purim" for English. That's not to say that you haven't heard what you've reported; it may be helpful to specify what type of community you've heard it in.

Comment: I was asked this by an Israeli friend who told me he heard it many times, also received notes which said it....

Comment: Also never heard of this.

Comment: Fwiw I've frequently seen שמחת פורים written as a wish/blessing in the States.

Comment: פורים שמחים Happies Purimses